# count the number of rows if conditions are true in 3 columns

Tags: excel-formula

I need to count the number of rows if conditions are true in 3 columns.
Currently I am using the below formula, but I need to sum for almost `500` odd rows...

How can this be done using array formulas...

Any Ideas?

```
=IF(AND(B4="B1",F4="D",AM4="X"),1,0)
```

Comment: Link to Microsoft page explaining `COUNTIFS` - [See Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Answer (score 0):

`=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$500,"B1",$F$1:$F$500,"D",$AM$1:$AM$500,"X")` will give you the result you want. It uses the structure of Criteria Range 1, Criterion 1, Criteria range 2...etc. You can include up to (IIRC) 127 conditions. Put that formula into a single cell and you'll see the result in that cell. You can also use cell references for the conditions and put your criterion into cells for easier modification or updating.